# After merging, the column used to merge lost

Tags: r, data.table

If I run below codes

```
dt<-data.table(col1=c(0,1,2),col2=c("a","b","c"),col3=c("aa","ab","cc"))
setkey(dt,col1)
dt1<-data.table(a=c(1,2))
dt[dt1]
```

I got below results

```
   col1 col2 col3
1:    1    b   ab
2:    2    c   cc
```

However, the expected result is

```
   a col1 col2 col3
1:      0    a   aa
2: 1    1    b   ab
3: 2    2    c   cc
```

How to get the expected result?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, I am reading the post as: "merge data.table on key(s) and keep the columns from both tables?"

Comment: It might be related to this FR: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1615 Sounds like they're working on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're ok modifying `dt`:

```
dt[dt1, a := i.a][]
#   col1 col2 col3  a
#1:    0    a   aa NA
#2:    1    b   ab  1
#3:    2    c   cc  2
```

If you're not, `copy()` it first.

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: @eddi Would you mind adding a little bit of text to explain what "i.a" is doing? I do not see this syntax in `help(":=")`.

Comment: @lmo you can find it in `?data.table`: *"Advanced: When i is a data.table, the columns of i can be referred to in j by using the prefix i., e.g., X[Y, .(val, i.val)]. Here val refers to X's column and i.val Y's"*

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a closer look there.

Answer (score 1):

Your expected results are not consistent to base R merge.
You expect to get LEFT OUTER JOIN while R base is designed to perform RIGHT OUTER JOIN.
Solution is just to swap tables.

```
library(data.table)
dt<-data.table(col1=c(0,1,2),col2=c("a","b","c"),col3=c("aa","ab","cc"))
dt1<-data.table(a=c(1,2))
dt1[dt, .(a = x.a, col1, col2, col3), on = c("a"="col1")]
#    a col1 col2 col3
#1: NA    0    a   aa
#2:  1    1    b   ab
#3:  2    2    c   cc
```

Additionally, you have to explicitly ask for `x.a` column, also due to R base consistency on that matter.
The `x.col` notation in `j` was recently implemented in data.table 1.9.7 version. You can [install](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) it by

```
install.packages("data.table", type = "source",
                 repos = "https://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table")
```

But if you don't care on updating your `dt` object then it is more efficient to use @eddi answer which adds column by reference.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. BTW, if I use copy() first, as @eddi mentioned, dt will not be updated.

Comment: @NewGuyComesIn yes, that is of course another option